# Terminology for f(g(x)) = g(f(x))

Tags: circuit-complexity, terminology, functional-programming

There is a [paper by Ritt from 1923](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1923-025-03/S0002-9947-1923-1501252-3/S0002-9947-1923-1501252-3.pdf) that calls the relation,  $f(g(x)) = g(f(x))$, *permutable functions*. Is there a more recent terminology used in the literature, or is this still the standard?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's common to say that $f$ and $g$ commute with respect to composition (where the property is known as commutativity). See, e.g., http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition.